# How to save and download text file in Flutter web application

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web

I am new to Flutter and working in a flutter web application, My requirement is to create and download a text file. like below.

```dart
void getData() {
    List<int> bytes = utf8.encode('this is the text file');
    print(bytes); // Need to download this with txt file.
}
```

Can anyone help me to achieve this

Answer (score 65):

This method is based on manipulations with an `HTML` document.
Some additional packages should be imported:

```dart
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:html' as html; // or package:universal_html/prefer_universal/html.dart
```

Code snippet:

```dart
final text = 'this is the text file';

// prepare
final bytes = utf8.encode(text);
final blob = html.Blob([bytes]);
final url = html.Url.createObjectUrlFromBlob(blob);
final anchor = html.document.createElement('a') as html.AnchorElement
  ..href = url
  ..style.display = 'none'
  ..download = 'some_name.txt';
html.document.body.children.add(anchor);

// download
anchor.click();

// cleanup
html.document.body.children.remove(anchor);
html.Url.revokeObjectUrl(url);
```

[Here](https://dartpad.dev/90528a2a477d037ee8beddb297e6f98b) is `DartPad` demo.

Comment: Thanks! It feels a bit hacky but it works. 

Unfortunately, I don't get the "Save As" dialog in Chrome, it just starts downloading a file. And I have "Ask where to save each file before downloading" setting turned ON.

Comment: @OleksiiShliama If you look into the FileSaver.js library its actually doing the exact same thing what Spatz has done :) . check [here](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/blob/master/src/FileSaver.js#L72). Also the save as dialog appears for me in chrome. Could be a version issue..?

Comment: DartPad download button does not download any file?

Comment: @Abdullah Khan thanks! Indeed blocked in chrome because of [new security restrictions](https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5706745674465280) but still works in Firefox.

Comment: @Spatz thanks for the information. Is there any way to download files using flutter web?

Comment: @Abdullah Khan this code still works - problems only with sandboxed iframe (dartpad uses one internally).

Comment: @Spatz Their is a small problem. If an API is returning a file URL in form of bytes(Uint8List). Api can return .jpg, .png, .pdf, .mp3 etc. Now how to download this type of file and how to convert URL to bytes?

Comment: @Abdullah Khan this is beyond the scope of original problem. Feel free to ask new question, but be more specific about api and file formats - it's a very broad topic.

Comment: I have the problem using `final bytes = utf8.encode(text)`. "Líder" results in "LÃ­der" on file. I tried `final bytes = text.codeUnits` to get unicode but the results does not convert to caracter, it stay a list of int numbers "[71, 114, 117, 112,..]" on file. Is there a way to resolve this problem?

Comment: Yeah I think this really only works for ascii text.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This works for pdf files too if you can get the pdf content in bytes to be placed in the Blob

Comment: Hi @Spatz this answer works. However, I have a question, how do I choose where to download the file?

Comment: @MyCar for security reason, it can't be done from code.

Comment: still works, needs just some minor tweaks to adapt to null safety

Answer (score 17):

Got another way to do it, via popular JS library called [FileSaver](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js)

First, update your `ProjectFolder/web/index.html` file to include the library and define the `webSaveAs` function like so:

```
...

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/FileSaver.js/1.3.8/FileSaver.min.js"> 
</script>

<script>
function webSaveAs(blob, name) {
  saveAs(blob, name);
}
</script>

<script src="main.dart.js" type="application/javascript"></script>

...
```

Then you can call this function from Dart code like so:

```
import 'dart:js' as js;
import 'dart:html' as html;

...

js.context.callMethod("webSaveAs", [html.Blob([bytes]), "test.txt"])
```

Comment: there's a small typo in the final line.  Here it is with the list literals as well  js.context.callMethod('webSaveAs', <dynamic>[
        html.Blob(<List<int>>[bytes]), 'test.txt'
      ]);    (you can get rid of <dynamic> and <List<int>> if your linter isn't giving you a warning.

Answer (score 17):

If you are looking to simply save a text file, this method is more straight forward than having to deal with all those conversions:

```
import 'dart:convert' show utf8;

// ignore: avoid_web_libraries_in_flutter
import 'dart:html' show AnchorElement;

void saveTextFile(String text, String filename) {
  AnchorElement()
    ..href = '${Uri.dataFromString(text, mimeType: 'text/plain', encoding: utf8)}'
    ..download = filename
    ..style.display = 'none'
    ..click();
}
```

You can change the mimeType and encoding as you see fit. For instance, I had to generate CSV files in a recent project, so I used `mimeType: 'text/csv'`.

Comment: How can I make this work with any file type?

Comment: @markhorrocks You can simply just set the filename and the mimeType for the corresponding file type. Note that what I detailed above only works for text-based files. If you are dealing in binary data, you will need to use a different approach (such as replacing the `Uri.dataFromString` above with [`Uri.dataFromBytes`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.18.0/dart-core/Uri/Uri.dataFromBytes.html)).

Answer (score 4):

This solution uses FileSaver.js library and it should open the "saveAs" dialog.

I hope it works as intended:

```
import 'dart:js' as js;
import 'dart:html' as html;

...

final text = 'this is the text file';
final bytes = utf8.encode(text);

final script = html.document.createElement('script') as html.ScriptElement;
script.src = "http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/g/filesaver.js";

html.document.body.nodes.add(script);

// calls the "saveAs" method from the FileSaver.js libray
js.context.callMethod("saveAs", [
  html.Blob([bytes]),
  "testText.txt",            //File Name (optional) defaults to "download"
  "text/plain;charset=utf-8" //File Type (optional)
]);

 // cleanup
 html.document.body.nodes.remove(script);
```

Comment: I keep getting a "saveAs method not found" error.  Has anyone else seen this?

Comment: I don't know why you keep getting that error. I'm sorry that I can't help

Comment: @HassanAnsari did u get it to work on a hosted site?

Comment: Yes, I did, and I created a plugin for saving file, on web it will download the file and on all other 5 platform it will be saved in documents folder. Here it is https://pub.dev/packages/file_saver

Answer (score 3):

I stumbled upon this and hardly found anything but this worked for me as of the latest flutter version 2.5.0.

you have to add this script in the body of your `web/index.html` file

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/amcharts/3.21.15/plugins/export/libs/FileSaver.js/FileSaver.min.js"></script>
```

and then just use this method to download any type of file

```dart
import 'dart:html' as html;
import 'dart:js' as js;

void save(Object bytes, String fileName) {
  js.context.callMethod("saveAs", <Object>[
    html.Blob(<Object>[bytes]),
    fileName
  ]);
}
```

e.g I wanted to download a JSON response from the server so I called it like this.

```
save(json.encode(response.data), 'file.json');
```

With this method you can almost download any type of file, I did use this method to download images and JSON files and it is pretty straightforward.

Comment: You should add that you need to import `'dart:js' as js;` and `'dart:html' as html;`

Comment: This builds for web but not linux. It can't find `dart:js` or `dart:html`. I need my app to be multi platform.