# How to make user download/save file from the flutter app?

Tags: flutter, dart, download

I want user to be able to store txt/doc/pdf file generated by flutter app wherever he/she wants on his/her phone. For example, if it were a webapp, this would be achieved by sending HTTP header `Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=MyFileName.txt`. Is it possible at all in flutter application? I tried looking at `url_launcher`, `flutter_downloader`, `flutter_webview_plugin` or `flutter_web_browser` packages, but non of them offer relevant functionality. I would appreciate any tips regarding this issue.

Comment: Looks like this might work: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61495252/50962

Comment: Nope, doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

**Getting the directory**

You can use [flutter_file_dialog](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_file_dialog#-example-tab-) to get the user the choose the location with this code:

```
final params = SaveFileDialogParams(sourceFilePath: "path_of_file_to_save");
final filePath = await FlutterFileDialog.saveFile(params: params);
print(filePath);
```

**Saving the file**

For that just use path_provider : https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/persistence/reading-writing-files

Comment: I am getting an exception that the source file is not found while I am specifying correct path from the root of the project registered in assets section of `pubspec.yaml`. does it have to be full device path? how is it possible to get one? btw, tbh, I don't really understand why I need to specify `sourceFilePath: "path_of_file_to_save"` if I am composing content after getting `filePath` anyway.

Comment: Assets and local storage are two different things, see my response here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62499275/5990125