# How can I overwrite an assets image in Flutter having a source image?

Tags: file, flutter, dart, assets, overwrite

I'm fairly new to Dart and Flutter, and I'm having trouble to overwrite an existing assets image from a source image.

My attempt:

```
try {
 File localFile = File('assets/images/myImage.png');
 localFile.writeAsBytesSync(originFile.readAsBytesSync());
catch (e) {
 log(e.toString());
}
```

I get:

```
[log] FileSystemException: Cannot open file, path = 'assets/images/myImage.png' (OS Error: No such file or directory, errno = 2)
```

I did define the assets folder in *pubspec.yaml*:

```
 assets:
    - assets/images/
```

Ok, so I've read somewhere that the asset file can be accessed like this:

```
import 'package:flutter/services.dart' show rootBundle;
final byteData = await rootBundle.load('assets/images/myImage.png');
```

But I don't know how to convert *byteData* to a *File* object that represents the actual file.

I think I'm missing something very basic here. Or maybe is there is a proper way to do this that has nothing to do with this approach?

Please help.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

If you want to write a file on a user device you should look here: https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/persistence/reading-writing-files

Shared preferences are a space in a phone where you app can write, so it's exactly what you want!

Assets are part of you app and are not meant to be modified within the app.

> During a build, Flutter places assets into a special archive called
> the asset bundle that apps read from at runtime. [According to the flutter website](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/assets-and-images#asset-bundling)

Hope this helps!