# Open generated file (Uint8list) in default application in Flutter

Tags: flutter, file, generated, uint8list

My application is generating excel and pdf reports. They are generated in Uint8list.
Is there a way to open such files in default application?

I tried open_file package, however, it requires a file path while my file is in memory.
same with url_launcher.

Also I tried saving the file then using open_file, but it doesn't work on web as file can't be saved.

Comment: Well you can use [file_saver](https://pub.dev/packages/file_saver) for web or refer to this for various methods of saving file on web [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59663377/how-to-save-and-download-text-file-in-flutter-web-application)

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by using printing.dat package. it has a PdfPreview that takes Uin8list and shows a preview with so many other options.