# How to download generated csv file in Flutter Web

Tags: flutter, csv, download

I am going to use http://pub.dev/packages/csv to generate a cvs file.

Once this is done, and stored in String variable, how to I download it on Flutter web with a click of a button?

Thank you.

Comment: see if this is helpful => https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59663377/how-to-save-and-download-text-file-in-flutter-web-application

Comment: Thank you, yes. I had seen that answer before and lost it. I'll try those

Comment: @ClevinoAlrin I used one of those answers. Should I close the question?

Comment: Just added a solution specific to your CSV use case, please let me know if that works! I didn't see anything like this in the linked post.

Comment: sure thing! Do check the answer once.... if it works you can mark it as accepted and then close.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Here is the complete working solution you were looking for:**

***Step 1:***
First of all you will need to install 2 packages in your Flutter project:

1. [csv](https://pub.dev/packages/csv)
2. [file_saver](https://pub.dev/packages/file_saver)

as shown below in my `pubspec.yml` file:

```yaml
name: csvwebdemo
description: A new Flutter project.
publish_to: 'none'
version: 0.1.0

environment:
  sdk: '>=3.1.0 <4.0.0'

dependencies:
  csv: ^5.0.2
  file_saver: ^0.2.8
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_lints: ^2.0.0

flutter:
  uses-material-design: true
```

***Step 2:***
Copy the `downloadCSV` function from my code, call that function in your download button, and pass the CSV String in it.

Here is my full code for your reference:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

// add following imports
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:typed_data';
import 'package:csv/csv.dart';
import 'package:file_saver/file_saver.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MainApp());
}

class MainApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MainApp({super.key});

  @override
  State<MainApp> createState() => _MainAppState();
}

class _MainAppState extends State<MainApp> {
  // Test CSV created just for demo.
  String csv = const ListToCsvConverter().convert(
    [
      ["Column1", "Column2"],
      ["Column1", "Column2"],
      ["Column1", "Column2"],
    ],
  );

  // Download and save CSV to your Device
  downloadCSV(String file) async {
    // Convert your CSV string to a Uint8List for downloading.
    Uint8List bytes = Uint8List.fromList(utf8.encode(file));

    // This will download the file on the device.
    await FileSaver.instance.saveFile(
      name: 'document_name', // you can give the CSV file name here.
      bytes: bytes,
      ext: 'csv',
      mimeType: MimeType.csv,
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child:
              // Download button UI code
              TextButton(
            onPressed: () async {
              //When the download button is pressed, call `downloadCSV` function and pass the CSV string in it.
              await downloadCSV(csv);
            },
            child: const Text(
              'Download',
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Output:
[image]

Here is how downloaded file looks like:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I've had success with the [file_saver](https://pub.dev/packages/file_saver) package.

Install package:

```bash
flutter pub add file_saver
```

Dart code:

```dart
// Your csv string
String myCsv = '...';

// Convert it to bytes
List<int> encodedCsv = utf8.encode(source);
Uint8List csvBytesList = Uint8List.fromList(list);

// Issue the save call!
String path = await FileSaver.instance.saveFile(
   name: 'Name of File',
   bytes: csvBytesList,
   ext: 'csv',
   mimeType: MimeType.csv,
);
```